# Incomplete data transfer: large CSV data Import, computation outputs exported as MX, then import the MX data

Tags: export, import, csv-format

I have a very large `CSV` data file, which I imported it to my active Notebook:

```
data = Import["filepath/myData.csv"];  (* data is a square matrix*)
```

Some calculations:

```
output = Inverse[data];
```

Then:

```
Export["output.mx", newFile];
```

Then:

```
Import["newFile.mx"]
```

To Extract the first 3 columns:

```
newFile[[All,3]]
```

I only get the 1st column because `Import` does not take the entire file. Why?

Comment: I think you meant `newfile[[All, ;;3]]` to get the first three columns. Your `newFile[[All, 3]]` means "take only the third column of all rows". Also confused by your code here: What is in the variable `newFile`? Did you mean that to be `output`? Also, you export to "output.mx", but import from "newFile.mx": is that right?

Comment: @MarcoB: You are right in all of your comments. I confused myself with `newFile`, with which I meant `output`. All these data operations with `import/export` aim to circumvent my computer's RAM problem. I do calculations to produce the `output` but at the time the `output` is produced, RAM is full. Therefore, I save the `output` to my hard disk & recall it for further calculations. Can you suggest the shortest way of doing what I described here? Thanks for your comment and would accept it as an answer if you post it.

Comment: My first recommendation would be to [avoid inverting the matrix](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/) altogether, if you can (and you generally can). What do you want to do with that inverse? It might perhaps be best to abandon this question (delete it / close it) and ask a new one focusing on your underlying problem of avoiding matrix inversion / saving memory. An example of a matrix that will cause the problem (you can put it in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)) and code to show what you want to achieve with it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to @MarcoB as he suggested the following answer to my question that arose from a programming mistake. I am providing his answer to help others who may face the same issue.

Create a matrix `mmB` (can be a very very large matrix) and `Save` it as an `MX` file because it is the format that allows the fastest data transfer:

```
Export["mmB.mx", mmB];  (*exported to the hard disk*)
```

Then, retrieve it for further computations:

```
Import["mmB.mx"];
```

`MX` format is really the fastest data packing, and this `Export/Import` method is useful especially for those who have RAM limitations.

Comment: I don’t think this answers your question nor do I really know what your question/goal was. Can you, please, further clarify this in your original question? What is the issue that you run into? This, to my understanding, would not circumvent “RAM limitations” as you have said, purely due to the fact that if you are not `Quit`-ing between these runs, the data continues to live in the kernel even after the `Export` is performed. You might also benefit from looking into the `DumpSave` function that is the intended means to save an expression/data in the`MX` format.

Comment: @CA Trevillian: You might want to read my reply to `@MarcoB` above. I face the RAM problem as I have a large CSV matrix plus performed various operations with it. I convert the CSV data to `MX` and keep it on my hard disk and retrieve it when needed. I avoided the RAM limitation by doing this. I will take a look at `DumpSave` function. Thanks for your comments.